# How can I make MLP with weights from tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I build Neural network in tensorflow and trained it.
I extracted weights and bias from estimator

```
weights1 = self.model.get_variable_value('dense/kernel')
bias1 = self.model.get_variable_value('dense/bias')
weights2 = self.model.get_variable_value('dense_1/kernel')
bias1 = self.model.get_variable_value('dense_1/bias')
...
```

And I build MLP with numpy in python

```
layer1 = np.dot(inputs, weight1)
layer1 = np.add(layer1, bias1)
layer1 = np.maximum(layer1, layer1 * 0.2, layer1)
...
```

I used leaky_relu activation function, so I was implemented it too but the output is completely different with from tensorflow. I don't know what's wrong about it.

Edit)

```
def my_dnn_regression_fn(features, labels, mode, params):
    top = tf.feature_column.input_layer(features, params["feature_columns"])

    for units in params.get("hidden_units", [20]):
        top = tf.layers.dense(inputs=top, units=units, activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu)

    output_layer = tf.layers.dense(inputs=top, units=1)

    predictions = tf.squeeze(output_layer, 1)

    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
            mode=mode, predictions={"label": predictions})

    average_loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels, predictions)

    batch_size = tf.shape(labels)[0]
    total_loss = tf.to_float(batch_size) * average_loss

    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
        mse = tf.metrics.mean_squared_error(labels, predictions)
        rmse = tf.metrics.root_mean_squared_error(labels, predictions)
        absolute_error = tf.metrics.mean_absolute_error(labels, predictions)
        mre = tf.metrics.mean_relative_error(labels, predictions, labels)

        tf.summary.scalar('mse', mse[1])
        tf.summary.scalar('mre', mre[1])
        tf.summary.scalar('rmse', rmse[1])
        tf.summary.scalar('absolute', absolute_error[1])

        # vars = tf.trainable_variables()
        # lossL2 = tf.add_n([tf.nn.l2_loss(v) for v in vars]) * 0.001

        l1_regularizer = tf.contrib.layers.l1_regularizer(
            scale=0.001, scope=None
        )
        weights = tf.trainable_variables()  # all vars of your graph
        lossL1 = tf.contrib.layers.apply_regularization(l1_regularizer, weights)

        # average_loss = tf.add(average_loss, lossL2)
        average_loss = tf.add(average_loss, lossL1)

        total_loss = tf.to_float(batch_size) * average_loss

        optimizer = params.get("optimizer", tf.train.AdamOptimizer)
        optimizer = optimizer(params.get("learning_rate", None))
        train_op = optimizer.minimize(
            loss=average_loss, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
        # eval_metrics = {"rmse": rmse, "absolute": absolute_error, "mre": mre}
        eval_metrics = {"mse": mse, "rmse": rmse, "absolute": absolute_error, "mre": mre}
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
            mode=mode, loss=total_loss, train_op=train_op, eval_metric_ops=eval_metrics)

    assert mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL

    mse = tf.metrics.mean_squared_error(labels, predictions)
    rmse = tf.metrics.root_mean_squared_error(labels, predictions)
    absolute_error = tf.metrics.mean_absolute_error(labels, predictions)
    mre = tf.metrics.mean_relative_error(labels, predictions, labels)

    eval_metrics = {"mse": mse, "rmse": rmse, "absolute": absolute_error, "mre": mre}

    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
        mode=mode,
        loss=total_loss,
        eval_metric_ops=eval_metrics)
```

My dnn regrassion code!!

Comment: What is the point doing that with numpy when the premade neural network from tensorflow do the job itself ? Why do you want to impose wieghts when they are already learnt by training ?

Comment: Tensorflow prediction is too slow :( . I need to predict one by one with my real time simulation, so I want to build it with numpy. it 10 times faster than tensorflow. should just I use another learning tool for this?

Comment: You should be able to do that with Tensorflow with the `predict` function, however i recommend you to use Keras which is a high level api based on Tensorflow.
And yes, numpy is probably faster but Tensorflow has very good performances too, it's surprising that you find it too slow

Comment: Yes tensorflow is fast, but I have to predict one by one, not like predict all dataset in one time. and when I use that predicted num, it tooks 0.1 seconds for extract tensor to value. 0.1 sec is huge for me. I'll try Keras. Thx

Comment: Try to check output of every layer, start from the first layer in tensorflow model and your numpy model. Can you show how you implement tensorflow model and how you use it in prediction stage?